# SurfaceView is displaying camera feed sideways

Tags: java, android

For some reason the camera feed in my program is sideways. If I hold my finger up to the camera from the bottom, it shows up as coming from the right in the surfaceview.

I have a pretty standard implementation

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

I've looked around but I can't seem to find any information on this. My device is a nexus One.

EDIT: If I set the screen orientation to landscape then it works fine for some reason... Can't get it in portrait though.

Comment: I had this problem a while back as well and never got around to solving it. I don't really think the problem is in the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of the preview display image is controlled by [Camera.setDisplayOrientation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) method.  For my Evo, setting the orientation to 90 makes the preview display correct for portrait mode.

```
...
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.setDisplayOrientation((orientation+90)%360);
camera.startPreview();
...
```

It seems that changing the orientation after the preview is started causes an exception.  If you change rotate the phone/device, the SurfaceHolder.surfaceChanged callback will be called again, if you do the setDisplayOrientation and startPreview in that callback, you get an exception.  I'm, going to try stopping preview, then changing the orientation then starting it again.

Note: There is also the [Camera.Parameters.setRotation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) method, that (I think) changes the orientation of the image when it is written into the (JPEG) output image when a picture is taken.  This method does not change the preview display orientation.

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
  mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

in surfaceCreated method after

```
  mCarmera.open();
```